# How to Extract Date From FileName using SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write the SQL statement to get the date from different file names. These file names might change. But, it contains date in a format of (MonthName Date YYYY) in the file name. For example, May 18 2022 in file name "AAAA May 18 2022 - User List - AAAA user list_20220518_1858.csv". The location of date in file name is not fixed. Below is an example of various file names for reference. "AAAA" is the name of company.

File Name Examples:

1. AAAA May 18 2022 - User List - AAAA user list_20220518_1858.csv
2. AAAA User Report September 1 2021 - AAAA user list.csv
3. November 2021 - AAAA User List - AAAA Main - User List.csv
4. AAAA May 18 2022 - User List - AAAA user list_20220518_1858_20220616.csv
5. October 2021 - AAAA User List - AAAA - Cybersource user list (4).csv
6. AAAA May 18 2022 - User List - AAAA user list_20220518_1858.csv

Here is what I tried for some of the file names:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100) ='AAAA User Report September 1 2021 - AAAA user list.csv'
        SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(replace(@FileName, 'AAAA User Report', ''), 1, CHARINDEX('-', replace(@FileName, 'AAAA User Report', ''), 1) - 2) AS datetime) AS FileDate
```

AND

```
        DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100) ='November 2021 - AAAA User List - AAAA Main - User List.csv'
        SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(replace(@FileName, 'AAAA User List', ''), 1, CHARINDEX('-', replace(@FileName, 'AAAA User List', ''), 1) - 2) AS datetime) AS FileDate
```

I would like to write a single SQL statement to address all the file names irrespective of the location of the date mentioned in file names. Can someone please help/advise on regex/sql query?

Comment: why does the "system" that generates the CSV file not using a constant naming convention - which would make this task a to minute job?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multiple systems generating different files with same columns. So, that's why, I am not able to fix the file name formats.

Comment: Inconsistent file names is a strong indication you have live humans typing out these names at some point. If that's true, the odds of your humans consistently following the `MMMM [dd] yyyy` naming convention are effectively **zero**. That means you're back to needing to parse random date formats out of the text, and this is not a solved problem in any platform.

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: This is nearly impossible to automate. And even worse when you have at least one example with only a partial date. And then the idea that location can move around. This logic is insanely difficult with any programming language, but with sql server it is futile.